# DataGridView carrega os dados mas exibe em branco

Tags: c#, datagridview

Tenho um DataGridView, ele carrega os dados, mas não exibe eles.

```
 private void AtualizarGrid()
    {

        AlunoDAL alunoDAL = new AlunoDAL();

        var bindingList = alunoDAL.CarregarAlunos();
        AlunosColecao alunosColecao = new AlunosColecao();
        var source = new BindingSource(bindingList, null);

        dataGridViewAluno.DataSource = bindingList;
        dataGridViewAluno.DataSource = source;

        //Atualiza o Grid.
        dataGridViewAluno.Update();
        dataGridViewAluno.Refresh();
    }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Adicione um databind abaixo do grid.DataSource.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            var listaProdutos = new Produtos().ConsultarProdutos();
            if (listaProdutos != null && listaProdutos.Count > 0)
            {
                this.grdDados.DataSource = listaProdutos;
                this.grdDados.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: A aplicação é Windows Forms!